# SQL select sort combinating columns

Tags: sql, sqlite, sorting

I have a SQLite table with 2 columns defining the states of my data : `status` and `status_detail`. The definitive state of the data is the combination of these 2 status, e.g :

- state = 'new' when `status = 'open'` and `status_detail = 'init'`
- state = 'under_process' when `status = 'running'` and `status_detail = 'for_admins'`
- ...

I'm not very good at SQL, but I know how to do a simple "`ORDER BY`" (event with multiple columns :) ), but how can I sort using a combination of columns?

Comment: Hint:  `order by status, status_detail`.

Answer (score 1):

write both the column names with which you want to sort with the column that you want to take precedence in sorting to be written first.

```
Order By Status, Status_Detail
```